# How can I set my BASH history scrolling to filter by what I've already typed?

Tags: linux, bash, history

Given a history of commands:

```
1 pwd
2 mysql -u root -p
3 ps -ef | more
4 top
5 mysql -h 192.168.1.101 -u root -p
```

When you press the Up arrow, you scroll through all those commands.  I've read it somewhere before (and done it in my work PC) that you can set-up BASH such that when I first type `p` then press the Up arrow, it would only scroll through all commands in history that starts with "p" (`pwd` and `ps -ef | more`).  When I type `mysql` then press Up, then it would only scroll through all commands starting with "mysql".

I'd like to set my laptop to use this, but I can't find the instructions again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure incremental searching in `/etc/inputrc` (for machine-wide changes), or `~/.inputrc` (just for your user account).

Add these two lines:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Comment: `/etc/inputrc` requires root to edit and makes machine-wide changes, `~/.inputrc`, is editable by ordinary users and makes changes just for that user.

Answer (score 7):

Alternately, you could press `ctrl+R` to enter `reverse-i-search` mode. You can then start typing and it will find the first prior line that matches the string you type (ie, type `m` and it will jump back to `mysql -h 192.168.1.101 -u root -p`; then type `o` and it will jump back to `ps -ef | more` as that's the first line with `mo` in.

You can hit `ctrl+r` again to search for the match before that (ie, `ctrl+r,my,ctrl+r` would take you to the second-last command starting with `mysql`)

You can read more about searching Readline's [history search](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Searching), [commands for interacting with the history](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History), and how you can [modify the default keybindings and behavious](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Init-File) in `man bash` (or [online](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html))

Comment: works in zsh as well

Comment: Yup, I already use `Ctrl+R`. but sometimes, after I begin typing a long command, I suddenly need to check all similar commands I've used before. This happens when I type in a mysql command and have to scroll through commands in history with different parameters (database names, output file, input file, etc).